# How to make sure if an API is hit only by the designated app?

Tags: android, api, security, authorization, safetynet

Say, I have an API `/api/send-otp` which takes phone-number as input and sends otp to user's phone-number. Now, this API can not be authenticated because auth token is generated after successful `/api/confirm-otp` call.

How to make sure that the `/api/send-otp` call is coming only from the authorized **android** app and not from any script/client.

PS: I can't embed any hashing logic in apk as it can be reverse-engineered. Is something provided by Google (safety-net)? Any relevant documentation/implementation link would be helpful.

Comment: Well Safety-net is the best suitable scenario for your app...Refer this blog explain in detailed: https://medium.com/@hargoyal/secure-android-app-with-safetynet-8e367a1c8ad0 hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

> How to make sure that the /api/send-otp call is coming only from the authorized android app and not from any script/client

An easy way will be to pass along indicator param like `app_version` and check for it on the server side. If it doesn't exist un-authenticate the request.

Alternative, you can use old Google Play Services `GoogleAuthUtil`

> You use the GoogleAuthUtil class, available through Google Play services, to retrieve a string called an “ID Token”. You send the token to your backend and your backend can use it to quickly and cheaply verify which app sent it and who was using the app.

[Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html)

Also, there is another way, Google Sign in, mention in [this security blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html)

Comment: app_version can be easily intercepted and then the request can be sent via Postman/cURL

Comment: I agree. As your full code/resources are on the user side. they can get anything they want, it's just a matter of their seriousness..